# C# - filtering collection based on another collection exception

Tags: c#, linq, collections, filtering

I've searched through numerous examples on how to filter collection based on another collection and I have found an easy way, like so:

```
var oShipnotes = await DbContext.ShipNotes.Where(s => oManageRouteDto.ShipNotes.Any(mr => mr.Id == s.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

however it throws an exception that says it cannot be translated to SQL query.

Could anyone point me the right direction how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full exception message?

Comment: What version of Net/Core?  Not all Net queries will work with Core.

Answer (score 2):

Replace nested LINQ query to materialized list of identifiers:

```
// 1) get the list of target ship note identifiers
var ids = oManageRouteDto.ShipNotes.Select(mr => mr.Id).ToList();

// 2) pass this list into Where using Contains
var oShipnotes = await DbContext.ShipNotes.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

EF is aware of this pattern and translates `IList<T>.Contains` into SQL's `IN` condition.

Since EF deals with `IQueryable`s, each LINQ query must be translated into valid SQL expression. As a result, EF and underlying provider cannot translate *every* valid LINQ query (from C# perspective) just because SQL is not C#.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis for quick answer, works like a charm!